# JSR 352 Multiple Threads in a single partition?

Tags: java, batch-processing, partitioning, jsr352

Is it possible to have multiple threads in a single partition? if so, How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partitioned step will consist of multiple partitions, but each of the individual partitions of that step will run on a single thread.